# webpack-dev-server watches and compiles files correctly, but browser can't access them

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

**EDIT**: Link to github repo where this example is hosted is [here](https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/ci-examples/tree/master/webpack-angular) in case someone wants to run it

---

I'm getting the near exact same problem as another user (you can find the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039146/webpack-dev-server-compiles-files-but-does-not-refresh-or-make-compiled-javascri)), in that running the webpack-dev-server does actually compile and watch files correctly (seeing the console output in the terminal), but the browser still can't view my site correctly. This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path'),
    // webpack plugins
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
    context: path.join(__dirname,'app'),
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    devServer: {
        // contentBase: './public/'
    },
    plugins: [
        // copies html to public directory
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: path.join(__dirname, 'app', 'index.html'),
                to:  path.join(__dirname, 'public')}
        ]),
        // required bugfix for current webpack version
        new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // uses babel-loader which allows usage of ECMAScript 6 (requires installing babel-preset-es2015)
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/, query: { presets: ['es2015']}},
            // uses the css-loader (loads css content) and style-loader (inserts css from css-loader into html)
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css', exclude: /node_modules/}
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

And this is my directory structure:

```
+--- webpack/
   +--- app/
      +--- index.html
      +--- index.js
      +--- styles.css
   +--- package.json
   +--- webpack.config.js
```

Currently, running `webpack-dev-server` outputs the following in the browser (note the lack of the `public/` directory which is where webpack normally outputs my html and javascript bundle):

[image: Image 1]

[image]

---

**EDIT**: Adding the devServer.contentBase property and setting it to `public` gets the browser to return a 403 error not found as shown here:

[image]

Comment: how are you running the dev server from terminal?

Comment: `webpack-dev-server --colors --progress`

Comment: Noticed that your `contentBase` is commented out. https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html. Content base defaults to directory running the command if `contentBase` is not specified

Comment: [`publicPath`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) should not be a filesystem path.

Comment: Yup, but un-commenting it returns a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Just realized you were compiling before running the dev server. :P @sgarcia imho running webpack-dev-server after a compile defeats the purpose of running it. The dev server is meant to have a development server serving content from source and recompiling in memory on the fly as you change files. If you want a solid serving of your compiled bundle, express or koa or even nginx to serve the static content folder of the output

Comment: Oh, I'm not running it after a compile. I basically just do the `webpack-dev-server` run and do nothing else (I didn't run `webpack` before). Normally `webpack --watch` gets the job done, but I've seen highly recommended to use the dev-server. I was expecting the dev-server to work exactly the same :S @technicallyjosh

Comment: @sgarcia my mistake. I'm comparing your config right now with mine.

Comment: Thank you @technicallyjosh, I'm still checking out what could be wrong by doing many variations of this with different options and such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to reproduce the issue that you have on my project. To fix the issue I changed some things.

Here is what I have set up. I'm defining a bit less in the output and using jsx instead of js, but the results should be the same. You can replace my `src` with wherever your source code is.

```
const config = {
    entry: './src/App.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['add-module-exports']
                }
            },
            {
                include: /\.json$/, loaders: ['json-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css?modules', 'sass']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'Promise': 'exports?module.exports.Promise!es6-promise',
            'fetch': 'imports?self=>global!exports?global.fetch!isomorphic-fetch'
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, [/moment$/]),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./src')
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: 'src'
    }
};
```

So basically you would want this output in terminal:

[image: terminal example]

- `webpack result is served from /` - tells us that whatever we build from will be at the root
- `content is served from src` - tells us that it's building from that directory

Hope this helps

Comment: I solved it seconds before you posted your answer, and since yours is the closest anyone got I'll award best answer. The line that broke everything in my project was setting `config.output.publicPath` to a directory, when I should have been setting it to `/` or not setting it at all. Thank you for all your effort though Josh!

Comment: Ah okay! Yeah I ended up omitting that in my config. Good find. No problem! Always nice to troubleshoot and learn new things. Happy coding.