# React Hot Loader v4.0.0 + Webpack 4 dev Server Not Updating App

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr

WebSocket connection seems to be establish but no modules get refreshed.

Chrome console output:

```
client?ecf9:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?ecf9:223 [WDS] App hot update...
2client?ecf9:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?ecf9:223 [WDS] App hot update...
2client?ecf9:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?ecf9:223 [WDS] App hot update...
2client?ecf9:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?ecf9:223 [WDS] App hot update...
2client?ecf9:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client?ecf9:223 [WDS] App hot update...
```

Notice the multiple recompiles on every change.

Answer (score 1):

@faceyspacey.com helped me with this on codementor.

React Hot Loader was not updating modules due to a circular dependency in root component. To troubleshoot this type of issue @faceyspacey.com recommended temporarily moving the hot load marker down to a component lower in the component tree.

People facing similar symptoms may find this Q&A useful as well:
[Webpack-dev-server compiles files but does not refresh or make compiled javascript available to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039146/webpack-dev-server-compiles-files-but-does-not-refresh-or-make-compiled-javascri)