# Hot reloading for webpack-dev-server is not working when the nested directory structure is passed as output and contentBase parameter

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-reload

I got the webpack-dev-server hot reloading feature working with the following webpack.config.js file.

```
    mode: 'development',
    watch: true,
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/app.js'),
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchContentBase: true,
        port: 9001
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
```

Index.html serves to

```
 <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

What i am trying to do right now is refactor the directories so that the bundle.js will fall into public/build and index.html will fall into public/dist. So i changed my webpack.config.js as following

```
    mode: 'development',
    watch: true,
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/app.js'),
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        watchContentBase: true,
        port: 9001
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public','build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
```

Index.html serves to

```
 <script src="../build/bundle.js"></script>
```

But the above config does not work and i get bundle.js config not found.
My express server is serving the static path as follows.

```
const publicPath=path.join(__dirname,'..','public')
console.log('publicpath',publicPath);
app.use(express.static(publicPath))
```

Any reason why the directory structure fail to work with HMR?

Attached is my directory structure.

[image: Sandbox directory Structure]

Comment: Maybe this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039146/webpack-dev-server-compiles-files-but-does-not-refresh-or-make-compiled-javascri

Comment: @IshitaSingh Thank you. One of the comment in the link provided by you, resolved my issue.