# webpack dev server: received "Hot Module Replacement enabled" but my page does not change

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying use webpack-dev-server to run a simple webpage. I can see my page in http://localhost:8080/, but whatever setting I do cannot run hot reload properly, when I click `ctrl s`, my console.log would immediately show something like:

`[WDS] Live Reloading enabled.`

My cmd show:

`｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.`
`｢wdm｣: Compiling...`

But after these, my page still not change. I need to run `npm run build` to see how my code work.

my project structure is like this:

```
folder
-index.html
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
-src
---router
-----router.js
---views
-----header.vue
-----footer.vue
-----cat1.vue
```

here's my code.

```
<!-- index.html  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Vue.js v2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <isheader></isheader>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <isfooter></isfooter>
  </div>
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack0409",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');  
const webpack = require('webpack');

var path = require('path')
var config = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/router', 'router')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: './'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: { name: 'image/[name].[ext]' }
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
      node_modules: __dirname + '/node_modules'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({ 
      template: './index.html' 
    }),
  ]
}
module.exports = config
```

header

```
<template>
<div>
    <div style="background: #44bb55;">
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
        <p>header</p> 
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

header, footer, cat1, these 3 files' code are similar, only different in css style.
router-link can work correctly, just hot reload not work.

Is there any problem I make?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reading. I found someone has similar problem: [Webpack-dev-server compiles files but does not refresh or make compiled javascript available to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039146/webpack-dev-server-compiles-files-but-does-not-refresh-or-make-compiled-javascri)

Thougt I'm not much understand how it works, I remove publicPath in webpack.config.js

now it look like this:

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
```

and now my page can refresh properly.